# how can i get fonts for text from client pc using Java Applet?

Tags: java, applet

i am trying to get system fonts in applet form client side but it does not work for applet help required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get fonts using

```
GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font[] fonts = e.getAllFonts(); // Get the fonts
```

In [this applet](http://raphaello.univ-fcomte.fr/IG/Java2D/Exemples/ListeFontes/ListeFontes.htm), it seems to work correctly.